# What should I do, I receive a targeted DEATH comment?

Tags: discussion

@Clare ***DEATH.*** - Black and White

[image]

This comment was deleted after [I asked the commenter for clarification](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/413325/a-word-or-phrase-to-describe-citizens-of-a-country-who-are-naturally-inclined-to#comment987101_413325). I don’t know why it was deleted or by who(m). I hadn’t flagged it.  I don’t feel comfortable receiving such a comment.

[image]

ETA:  (And now my comment asking for clarification has been deleted. I have a screen grab on my device showing that comment as well.)

Comment: Posting here is probably all you can do, since it's no longer able to be flagged.

Comment: Moderators should treat this as a serious complaint. I am not talking about an individual member. Strict and severe moderator action (read maximum punishment) needs to be taken against *any* user posting such a comment.

Comment: Short comments are quickly automatically removed with 1-2 flags. Doesn't even require the usual 3-6 flags.

Comment: Aww, I remember being a jerk teenager long ago, before I became a jerk adult. Poor kid.

Comment: As the suspension indicates, that's not tolerated at EL&U. Thankfully, it isn't commonplace here. The user [attributed](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10692/suspensions-that-are-too-harsh#comment44170_10692) some of their previous posts to an older brother. If it's any comfort: it might well have been another prank. Regardless, I hope you're ok.

Comment: @Lawrence "Sebastian Pojman", "Edna Mode", and "Black and White". These are all names for the same user. I notice it now. Also, I have had a similar discussion with the user about identity confusion: https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10692/suspensions-that-are-too-harsh#comment44297_10702.

Answer (score 13):

Since you didn't have the opportunity to flag the comment (which is the preferred course of action), raising the matter on Meta is an option. However, it's not usually The Best Idea™ to raise this sort of thing in public: the general advice is (a) flag; (b) flag something else of the user's; (c) contact moderators in chat — we can open a private chatroom; (d) use the [Contact](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/contact) link at the bottom of every page to contact SE staff.

The comment is, on its own, rather cryptic. However, it is (I judge) a violation of the ["Be nice" policy](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice).

> 1. **Rudeness and belittling language are not okay.** Your tone should match the way you'd talk in person with someone you respect and whom you want to respect you. If you don't have time to say something politely, just leave it for someone who does.

> 3. **Don't be a jerk.** These are just a few examples. If you see them, flag them:
>      ...
>
>    - **Harassment and bullying.** If you see a hostile interaction, flag it. If it keeps up, *disengage* — we'll handle it. If something needs staff attention, you can use the contact us link at the bottom of every page.

Also, using the comment system as a private messaging channel — waiting for the notice to appear in the recipient's inbox and then deleting the comment — is an abuse. Comments are provided in order to allow asking for clarification or pointing out an egregious error in a post. Occasionally, a witty remark might be made in a comment and might resist deletion. However, excessive commenting is a template we have at our disposal in moderator messages, and abuse of the system — especially in what may be considered an underhand way — is unlikely to end well.

Note that we are not really at liberty to discuss individual users, their age or other personal circumstances or their past history, so I won't. Nor will we comment on this individual case other than the general statements in this answer. There is probably enough here to read between the lines.

Comment: I couldn't do option a,  I didn't think of b; I don't know how to do  c; I was unaware of  d (but now I am).

Comment: @Clare I don't think there are any negative side-effects to flagging your own comments for moderator attention to get the mod team's attention if you do it sparingly. If you explain what's going on, the mod team can see the deleted comments and take appropriate action.

Comment: @Clare Visit the [chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95/english-language-usage) and ping a moderator or two with `@username`. We'll take it from there, and can invite you to a private chatroom for the gory details.

Comment: I've done so with your name. I didn't even know meta had a chat room

Comment: @Clare Well, it does and it doesn't. The chatroom is connected to the entire site (Main and Meta). I've responded and you should have an inbox message about it.